# How to extract only certain values from cookies in a json file?

Tags: python, json, database, dictionary

Iam gathering cookies from a selenium browser and then writing them to a json file. I want to then read them and only extract the `name` and `value` keys and values. However, I dont know how to convert them back into a dictionary without changing the cookies in any way, which I see as a common answer on here.

Here are the cookies below

`[{"domain": ".instagram.com", "httpOnly": true, "name": "rur", "path": "/", "secure": true, "value": "PRN"}, {"domain": ".instagram.com", "expiry": 1610372060, "httpOnly": true, "name": "shbid", "path": "/", "secure": true, "value": "2630"}, {"domain": ".instagram.com", "expiry": 1610372060, "httpOnly": true, "name": "shbts", "path": "/", "secure": true, "value": "1609767261.111102"}, {"domain": ".instagram.com", "expiry": 1641303259, "httpOnly": true, "name": "sessionid", "path": "/", "secure": true, "value": "5973912167%3A79EfmCoMj2hdDd%3A29"}, {"domain": ".instagram.com", "expiry": 1641216860, "httpOnly": false, "name": "csrftoken", "path": "/", "secure": true, "value": "z1i7aU8fUnFkO7jXS8eOcVzmzQVfCFTP"}, {"domain": ".instagram.com", "expiry": 1672839253, "httpOnly": false, "name": "mid", "path": "/", "secure": true, "value": "X_MZVgALAAFI1JXJOTF_ZG-E-Cny"}, {"domain": ".instagram.com", "expiry": 1617543260, "httpOnly": false, "name": "ds_user_id", "path": "/", "secure": true, "value": "5973912167"}, {"domain": ".instagram.com", "expiry": 1672839253, "httpOnly": true, "name": "ig_did", "path": "/", "secure": true, "value": "AD703D6F-E24A-4485-A1EC-9736E40C19C3"}, {"domain": ".instagram.com", "httpOnly": true, "name": "urlgen", "path": "/", "secure": true, "value": "\"{\\\"86.15.149.131\\\": 5089}:1kwQ05:r7Bsx0VcOwuIw_rejyFuGdmgAIo\""}, {"domain": "www.instagram.com", "expiry": 4765462453, "httpOnly": false, "name": "ig_cb", "path": "/", "secure": false, "value": "2"}]`

Comment: Hey mate, from this list you just want to extract all the name and value ?

Comment: yes i want to extract all the names and values so i can then use them when sending  requests :)

Comment: But how do you want them ? Cause there are going to be 10 sets of 2 keys and 2 values. Do you want them all in a list for example ? or you want an other dict but just with 2 keys/values per dict ?

Comment: 10 sets of keys and values would be ideal as this is the format used when injecting cookies for use in the requests module something similar to cookies = `{'enwiki_session': '17ab96bd8ffbe8ca58a78657a918558'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know if this is exactly what you want but I extracted all the domain and value keys and value and put them back in a dictionary and put all the dictionary in a list

```
 var = *YOUR COOKIES LIST*

liste = []
for i in range(len(var)) : 
        #print(var[i]["domain"])
        #print(var[i]["value"])
        dic = {"domain":var[i]["domain"],"value":var[i]["value"]}
        liste.append(dic)
        
        
print(liste)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would have since you saved it as a file:

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    datas = json.load(f)
    
    for data in datas:
        print(data["name"], " : ", data["value"])
```

resulting in

```
rur  :  PRN
shbid  :  2630
shbts  :  1609767261.111102
sessionid  :  5973912167%3A79EfmCoMj2hdDd%3A29
csrftoken  :  z1i7aU8fUnFkO7jXS8eOcVzmzQVfCFTP
mid  :  X_MZVgALAAFI1JXJOTF_ZG-E-Cny
ds_user_id  :  5973912167
ig_did  :  AD703D6F-E24A-4485-A1EC-9736E40C19C3
urlgen  :  "{\"86.15.149.131\": 5089}:1kwQ05:r7Bsx0VcOwuIw_rejyFuGdmgAIo"
ig_cb  :  2
```